# sum from one table between dates of second table

Tags: sum, between, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a report table that has the following columns-

Item#/Location/Price Hold Date/ Price Execution date

And a sales  table with -

Item#/Location/Date/Units

I'm trying to sum the units between the two dates in report table matching them based on item number and location into something like -

Item/Location/Price Hold Date/Price Execution Date/ Total Units Sold

Comment: You can certainly join on same Item / Location plus sales Date between Price Hold Date and Price Execution Date, then SUM. What have you tried and where is the issue?

Comment: I was joining on itm# and location, but didn't know I could join a column between two row values...... PERFECT!!! Thanks